# How to map an IntStream to a list of Runnables?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to return a list of `n` empty runnables using `IntStream`, but I think I'm missing something:

```
public List<Runnable> getEmptyRunnables(int count) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, count)
       .mapToObj($ -> () -> {})  // IDE error: "target type of a lambda must be an interface" 
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: You could have used just this: `return Collections.nCopies(count + 1, () -> {});` to get similar result (no stream API though and one empty lambda shared through the list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly specify the generic type when calling the method `mapToObj`.

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 3)
   .<Runnable>mapToObj($ -> () -> {})
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
// or
List<Runnable> r = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 3)
   .mapToObj($ -> (Runnable) () -> {})
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What is the `$` for?

Comment: @K.Nicholas It is the index, which is unused.